# Как задать стиль для iframe Facebook?

Tags: javascript, iframe, css

Привет.

Мне нужно, чтобы iframe перекривал другие элементы. Просто добавить `z-index:100;`. 
Как добиться этого для iframe от  facebook?

Популярный способ:

```
var head = jQuery(".like_panel_facebook  iframe").contents().find("head");
    var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
              '.fb_iframe_widget_lift{z-index:1000} ' +
              '</style>';
    jQuery(head).append(css);
```

Не будет работать через ошибку:

**VM4717:2 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www...." from accessing a cross-origin frame.*/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь стили прописать в самом айфрэйме))

Начнем с того, что содержимое айфрэйма модифицировать нельзя.

Стили нужно на своей странице задавать

```
iframe {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Благодарен..